# I am initiating my activity in a fragment but the variables are getting null?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, nullpointerexception

This is the code for the activity class.

```
public class Form1Activity extends MainActivity {
    private EditText factory_name,cell_no, _email:
    private Spinner meter_type_spinner;
    private Button form1submitbutton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        factory_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.factorynameTF);
        cell_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cellnoTF);
        _email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailTF);

        meter_type_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.metertypedropdown);

        form1submitbutton = (Button) findViewById((R.id.form1submitbtn));

        List<String> metertype = new ArrayList<>();
        metertype.add("day");
        metertype.add("night");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adpterMeterType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, metertype);
        adpterMeterType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        meter_type_spinner.setAdapter(adpterMeterType);
    }
```

Here is the code of fragment where I am calling the activity. know please tell me what I have done wrong. Should I do all the Fields handling in fragment or make a seperate activity for every fragment to carry out the workings of views e.g Edit tex, spinners etc.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form1, container, false);
    context = rootView.getContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Form1Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Form1Activity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
`Intent intent = new Intent(context, Form1Activity.class)`;
startActivity(intent);
```